# Does the Chinese embassy in Mexico City issues dual-entry or 60-day tourist visas to third country citizens?

Tags: china, regulations, mexico, tourist-visas, embassies

I need to book my flight out of China for my visa application which I'll make soon here in Mexico City.

Normally you have a choice between single-entry, dual-entry, and multiple-entry tourist visas and at least a choice between 30 days per entry and 60 days per entry.

But not every embassy actually issues every possibility. On a previous trip I went to the Chinese consulate in Ho Chi Minh City in Vietnam and was told that they only issue single-entry 30-day visas despite all the other options being on the forms and on posters on the wall.

Has anybody had experience or heard or read from some traveller who's tried this?

Comment: I'll go there tomorrow morning and apply for two 60-day entries and return with an answer. Or maybe four working days later.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is purely anecdotal and will have to be independently verified. But since we have no better info as yet, this is what I have learned:

The Chinese consulate in Mexico City seems **only** to issue **30-day entries** and not longer, but does issue dual-entry as well as single-entry visas. The forms also include multiple-entry but as I've learned at three other Chinese embassies, just because it's on the form doesn't mean they issue those.

I thought I was requesting a single 90-day entry in the appropriate part of the form, but the receipt I was given to pick up my passport indicated a single 30-day entry.

When I went back to the consulate to ask about it the security guards assured me that only 30-day entries were granted and seemed to think I was confused about the difference between two or more entries adding up to 60 or 90 days. They did not let me back in to ask the consulate staff.

Had I known of this limitation in advance I may have instead chosen to book two 30-day entries and booked my flight out of China for a different date.

Hopefully somebody with better knowledge of the actual rules can add a more concrete answer at some point.